# Looping and updating variables

Tags: java, loops, blackjack

In this blackjack program, there is an issue with calculating the running count (two code blocks starting with remainingDecks). Essentially, I want the program to calculate the running card count at the beginning of a round, update it if the player or dealer hits and keep that count to later add it to the next round's final count (output as well). I don't seem to know how many variables to keep in mind and where to put them in the code as well as what the necessary calculations are. I have tried multiple times with the first round working properly but it would not add its count to the next round's.

The running count is a strategy to help players count the cards that are dealt during the whole game (not rounds). Players keep track of the high and low cards by giving them a value of +1 (for cards of value 2,3,4,5,6), 0 (for cards of value 7,8,9) and -1 (for cards of value 10,J,Q,K,A). As the cards are dealt, the player adds the values to a starting count of 0 throughout the whole game and uses this count to determine what kind of cards are in the shoe (un-dealt cards). For example, with the player having a count of +10 at any given moment lets him know that there are more high cards now in the shoe and vice-versa.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blackjack{

private static deckOfCards playingDeck;
private static Card[] playerHand;
private static Card[] dealerHand;
private static boolean turn;
private static boolean gameOver;
private static double oldCardCounter = 0.;
private static double newCardCounter = 0.;
private static double runningCountOld = 0.;
private static double runningCountNew = 0.;
private static double remainingDecks;



public Blackjack() throws IOException{

    playingDeck = new deckOfCards();
    playingDeck.shuffle();
    playerHand = new Card[10];
    dealerHand = new Card[10];
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Blackjack theGame = new Blackjack();

    playerHand[0] = playingDeck.dealCard();
    dealerHand[0] = playingDeck.dealCard();
    playerHand[1] = playingDeck.dealCard();
    dealerHand[1] = playingDeck.dealCard();

    //playerMoney holds players cash 
    double playerMoney = 10000.0;

    //Play the game while the player has money
    //Game loop
    while(playerMoney>0 && (playingDeck.getCurrentCard() < (playingDeck.getCard().length-1))){

        if(gameOver){
            //nullify the hand arrays
            playerHand = new Card[playerHand.length];
            dealerHand = new Card[dealerHand.length];
            playerHand[0] = playingDeck.dealCard();
            dealerHand[0] = playingDeck.dealCard();
            playerHand[1] = playingDeck.dealCard();
            dealerHand[1] = playingDeck.dealCard();
        }

        turn = true;
        gameOver = false;

        //Take Bet
        System.out.println("\nYou have $" + playerMoney + ", how much would you like to bet?");
        System.out.println("You should bet $" + betValue(newCardCounter, playerMoney));
        double playerBet = userInput.nextDouble();

        while((playerBet > playerMoney) && (turn = true)){
            //Break if they bet too much
            System.out.println("\nYou cannot bet more than you have.");
            playerBet = userInput.nextDouble();
        }

            System.out.println("\nAfter shuffling, the deck looks like: ");

            //theGame.playingDeck.displayDeck();

            System.out.println("\nDealing..."); 



            //Display player cards
            System.out.println("\nYour Hand:" + playerHand[0] + " and " + playerHand[1]);

            //Display dealer cards
            System.out.println("\nDealer Hand: " + dealerHand[0] + " and [hidden]" +dealerHand[1]);

            //Display Value
            System.out.println("\nYour hand is currently valued at: " + score(playerHand));

            if(score(playerHand) == 21){

                System.out.println("\nBlackjack! You win $" + playerBet);
                playerMoney += playerBet * 1.5;

                gameOver = true;
            }

            remainingDecks = Math.round(remainingCards()/52.);
            runningCountOld = (int) (cardCounter(playerHand) + cardCounter(dealerHand));
            runningCountNew += runningCountOld;
            oldCardCounter = runningCountNew/remainingDecks;

            oldCardCounter = Math.round((runningCountNew)/(remainingDecks));

            if((Math.round(oldCardCounter*100)/10 == 5) && oldCardCounter < 0){
                oldCardCounter = Math.floor(runningCountNew/remainingDecks);
            }
            System.out.println(remainingCards());
            System.out.println("\nThis running count is: " + runningCountNew);
            newCardCounter = oldCardCounter;
            System.out.println("\nThe true count is: " +newCardCounter);

        while(!gameOver){

            if(decisionMaking(newCardCounter)){
                System.out.println("You should hit");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You should stand");
            }

            //What do they want to do
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to (1)Hit or (2)Stand");
            int response = userInput.nextInt(); 

            //They hit
            if(response == 1){


                hit(turn);

                System.out.println("\nYour new score is " + score(playerHand));

                if(score(playerHand) > 21){

                    System.out.println("\nYou bust! You lose $" + playerBet);

                    playerMoney -= playerBet;

                    gameOver = true;
                }else if(score(playerHand) == 21){

                    System.out.println("\nYou win $" + playerBet);
                    playerMoney += playerBet;

                    gameOver = true;
                }
            }

            //Stand
            if(response == 2){

                stand(turn);
                System.out.println("\nYou stand! Dealer's turn");
                System.out.println("\nDealer Hand: " + dealerHand[0] + " and " + dealerHand[1]);

                while(score(dealerHand) < 17){

                    hit(stand(turn));
                }

                System.out.println("\nDealer's score is " + score(dealerHand));

                if(score(dealerHand) > 21){

                    System.out.println("\nDealer busts! You win $" + playerBet);
                    playerMoney += playerBet;

                    gameOver = true;
                }else if(score(playerHand) > score(dealerHand)){

                    System.out.println("\nDealer loses! You win $" + playerBet);
                    playerMoney += playerBet;

                    gameOver = true;
                }else if(score(dealerHand) > score(playerHand)){

                    System.out.println("\nDealer wins! You lose $" + playerBet);

                    playerMoney -= playerBet;

                    gameOver = true;
                }else if(score(dealerHand) == score(playerHand)){

                    System.out.println("\nTie! Game over!");

                    gameOver = true;
                }

                stand(gameOver);

            }
            remainingDecks = Math.round(remainingCards()/52.);
            runningCountOld = (int) (cardCounter(playerHand) + cardCounter(dealerHand));
            runningCountNew += oldCardCounter;
            oldCardCounter = runningCountNew/remainingDecks;

            oldCardCounter = Math.round((runningCountNew)/(remainingDecks));

            if((Math.round(oldCardCounter*100)/10 == 5) && oldCardCounter < 0){
                oldCardCounter = Math.floor(runningCountNew/remainingDecks);
            }
            System.out.println(remainingCards());
            System.out.println("\nThis running count is: " + runningCountNew);
            newCardCounter = oldCardCounter;
            System.out.println("\nThe true count is: " +newCardCounter);
        }
    }   
}

public static int score(Card[] hand){

    int aces = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int totalValue = 0;

    while(hand[counter] != null){
        if(hand[counter].getCardValue() == 11){ 

            if((totalValue + 1) <= 11){

            aces = 1;
            totalValue += 11;

            }else{

                totalValue += 1;
            }

        }else{

            totalValue += hand[counter].getCardValue();
        }

        counter++;
    }


    if((totalValue > 21) && (aces!=0)){

        totalValue -= 10;
    }


    return totalValue;
}

public static Card[] hit(boolean turn){

    if(turn){

        for (int i=0; i < playerHand.length; i++) {

            if(playerHand[i] == null){

                playerHand[i] = playingDeck.dealCard();
                System.out.println("\nYou get a " + playerHand[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        return playerHand;
    }else{

        for (int i=0; i < dealerHand.length; i++) {

            if(dealerHand[i] == null){

                dealerHand[i] = playingDeck.dealCard();
                System.out.println("\nDealer draws a " + dealerHand[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        return dealerHand;
    }
}

//added
public static boolean stand(boolean turns){

    if(turns){

        turns = false;
        return turns;
    }else{

        gameOver = true;
        return gameOver;    
    }
}

//AI Code
public static int cardCounter(Card[] hand){

    int i = 0;
    int cardCount = 0;
    while(hand[i] != null){

        if(hand[i].getCardValue() >= 2 && hand[i].getCardValue() <= 6){
            cardCount += 1;
        }else if(hand[i].getCardValue() >= 7 && hand[i].getCardValue() <= 9){
            cardCount += 0;
        }else if(hand[i].getCardValue() >= 10 && hand[i].getCardValue() <= 14){
            cardCount += -1;
        }
        i++;

        if( i == 312){
            break;
        }
    }

    return cardCount;
} 

public static int remainingCards(){

    int remainingCardCount = 0;

    remainingCardCount = (playingDeck.getCard().length) - playingDeck.getCurrentCard();

    return remainingCardCount;
}

public static boolean decisionMaking(double trueCount){

    if (score(playerHand) >= 2 && score(playerHand) <= 11) {

        return true;
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 12) {
        if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() >=7 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() <= 11) {
            return true;
        }else if(dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 2) {
            return (trueCount < 3.0);
        }else if(dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 3) {
            return (trueCount < 1.0);
        }else if(dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 4) {
            return (trueCount < 0.0);
        }else if(dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 5) {
            return (trueCount < -1.0);
        }else{
            return (trueCount < 0.0);
        }
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 13) {
        if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() >=7 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() <= 11) {
            return true;
        }else if(dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 2) {
            return (trueCount < 0.0);
        }else if(dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 3) {
            return (trueCount < -1.0);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 14) {
        if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() >=7 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() <= 11) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 15) {
        if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() >=7 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() <= 11 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() != 10) {
            return true;
        }else if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 10) {
            return (trueCount < 4.0);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 16) {
        if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() >=7 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() <= 11 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue() != 10 && dealerHand[0].getCardValue()!= 9) {
            return true;
        }else if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 10) {
            return (trueCount < 0.0);
        }else if (dealerHand[0].getCardValue() == 9) {
            return (trueCount < 5.0);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 17) {
        return false;
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 18) {
        return false;
    }else if (score(playerHand) == 19) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public static double betValue(double trueCount, double totalMoney){

    double advantage = -0.005;
    double betPercent = 0.76;
    double optimalBet;

    optimalBet = totalMoney * ((trueCount * Math.abs(advantage) + advantage)*betPercent);

    return optimalBet;
}
```

}

Comment: Since not everyone is familiar with the rules of blackjack, could you detail in your question exactly what you are trying to calculate?  In plain English and algebra, not code, please.

Comment: @markspace updated